# Can my WP7 app use Open SSL?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, certificate, isaserver

I have a WP7 app that communicates with the back-end via a WCF service.

A customer has asked if the app can be made more secure by communicating via an ISA server using Open SSL.

The ISA server would be public facing with the IIS Server hosting the WCF service behind a firewall. I will have to load the public cert onto the phone and have read that this can be achieved by emailing the cert then running the attachment.

I'm not clued up on ISA, Open SSL or certificates and am hoping someone can tell me if this is possible or not.

Any ideas?

Edit

I'm hoping for a little about how to configure the WCF proxy on the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the the Root CA of the cert on the phone.  You can do this a couple of ways.  The simplest would be to email it to the phone as an attachement (p7b format).  On the phone simply open the attachement and the phone will prompt you to install the cert (p7b).  This will install the cert into the cerificate store. A good way to test if it is working right is to hit an HTTPS web URL in IE from the phone, if you dont get any security prompts about an untrusted cert it is working correctly.

You will need to have your SSL terminate at the ISA/UAG box.  This would have the server cert set up on it and use it to secure the SSL channel for the web app.

More information on configuring publishing with UAG (next gen of ISA) is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee406221.aspx

Comment: Good stuff. Any ideas on how to configurethe wcf service on the client side?